# How to decompose a sentence into array values?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been coding a simple chat bot, and everything is done except for the sentence decomposition.

How would I create a function to decompose a sentence that does the following?

- Convert a sentence to lower case
- Filter out commas, exclamation points, and periods.
- Make each word of the sentence an array value.
- Return the array.

I'm still learning JavaScript, and would like to know how to best do this.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Do you have some coding examples of your efforts?

Comment: What is a 'word' in the sentence?

Comment: If you don't know what a word is, all you can do is split on whitespace, then do in-line replacement of characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be something like this:

```
var result = input.toLowerCase().match(/[\w'-]+/g);
```

The `toLowerCase` converts the string to lowercase, then `match` will find any sequence of one or more word characters (which includes letters, numbers, and underscores), apostrophes, or hyphens.

For example:

```
var input = "I'm still learning JavaScript, and would like to know how to best do this.";
var result = input.toLowerCase().match(/[\w'-]+/g);
console.log(result); // ["i'm", "still", "learning", "javascript", "and", "would", "like", "to", "know", "how", "to", "best", "do", "this"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
s = 'Filter out commas, exclamation points, and periods.';
arr = s.toLowerCase().replace(/[,!.]/g, ' ').split(/ +/).filter(Boolean);
//=> ["filter", "out", "commas", "exclamation", "points", "and", "periods"]
```